# WIX installer unresolved reference to custom action that uninstalls ClickOnce

Tags: wix, clickonce

I have a Wix installer for an add-in, that was previously installed via ClickOnce, and while running the MSI, it should uninstall the ClickOnce deployment.

Wunderlist was kind enough to share their code on github, but the support on it is dead, so I'm coming here and trying to generalize the question, while also including the link to anybody who searches for this on Stackoverflow.

Basically I included this snippet in my Product.wxs file:

```
<!--ClickOnce Uninstaller-->
<Property Id="CLICKONCEAPPNAME" Value="Application Name" />

<CustomAction Id="UninstallClickOnce"
              BinaryKey="ClickOnceUninstaller"
              DllEntry="UninstallClickOnce"
              Return="ignore" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="UninstallClickOnce" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<!--ClickOnce Uninstaller-->
```

I added the references to the **UninstallClickOnce** project that hosts the **ClickOnceUninstaller** custom action.
However, when trying to build the installer it shows the following message on the CustomAction tag:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Binary:ClickOnceUninstaller' in section 'Product:*'
```

Any obvious thing I'm missing?

Here's the link to the github project: https://github.com/6wunderkinder/Wunder.ClickOnceUninstaller

Comment: You need to add a <Binary> tag to your <Product>, this tag will reference the uninstaller program that you are asking run.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Will try it that way! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Shall I convert my comment into an answer for you?